# Stop inferior to start in python range

Tags: python, for-loop, range

I would like to read values from a text file if the file contains text after a given line `start_line`.

I am importing the file with this method:

```
with open("filename", "r") as file:
    file_contents = file.readlines()
```

Would it be a bad practice to then do:

```
for line in range(start_line, len(file_contents)):
    ... reading contents of line ...
```

I've noticed that range(start,stop) returns an empty list if start <= stop, and that the for loop is skipped.

Is it uselessly redundant to add before the loop:

```
if len(file_contents) > start_line:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using `range()` like that. You have already read all of the data into `file_contents`. Unless I have missed something, this

```
for line in file_contents[start_line:]:
    ... process data in line ...
```

will do what I think you want.

Answer (score 1):

The condition:

```
if len(file_contents) > start_line:
```

is de facto logically equivalent to what happens in the loop:

```
for line in range(start_line, len(file_contents)):
    ... reading contents of line ...
```

So it would be  a duplication of logically equivalent conditions - unnecessary at best.

Answer (score 1):

As an old dinosaur used to dealing with scarce resources I do not like to load a whole file in memory when it can be avoided. So I would do:

```
with open("filename", "r") as file:
    for numline, line in enumerate(file):      # skip up to start_line-1
        if numline == start_line - 1: break
    if num_line == start_line - 1:             # Ok file is long enough
        for line in file:                      # process end of file
            ...
```

But if you only process small files this would be a useless optimization...

Comment: In this case I'm only processing small files, but I might need this method for another case thanks.
I'm not sure I fully understand what you wrote though: shouldn't the condition of the 3rd line be a <=, and shouldn't the 4th line be on the second level of indentation (and thus be in the for loop)?

Comment: @Bielorusse: No. The first loop discards lines until either the end of file or start_line will be the next line. That's is the reason why it breaks at start_line -1. The following `if` comes after that loop (hence out of it) to differenciate between less that start_line lines and more that start_line lines. Only in the latter case we have something to process.

Comment: Oh ok I get it thank you. But it would have had the same behaviour without that 4th line wouldn't it? Or is it useful in some cases?